# Why 'fs' only persists file changes after end of program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have an application that persists its state on disk, when any state change occur it reads from file the old state, it changes the state on memory and persists on disk again. But, the problem is that store function is writing on disk only after close program. I don't know why?

```
const load = (filePath) => {
    const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(
        filePath, "utf8"
    );
    return JSON.parse(fileBuffer);
}

const store = (filePath, data) => {

    const contentString = JSON.stringify(data);
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, contentString);
}
```

To create a complete example, let's use `load-dataset` command, in the file "src/interpreter/index.js".

```
while(this.isRunning) {

    readLineSync.promptCL({
      "load-dataset": async (type, name, from) => {
          await loadDataset({type, name, from});
      },
      ...
    }, {
      limit: null,
    });
}
```

In general, this calls `loadDatasets`, which reads `json` ou `csv` files.

```
export const loadDataset = async (options) => {

  switch(options.type) {
    case "csv":
      await readCSVFile(options.from)      
      .then(data => {
        app.createDataset(options.name, data);
      });
      break;
    case "json":
      const data = readJSONFile(options.from);
      app.createDataset(options.name, data);
      break;
  }
}
```

The method `createDataset()` read the file on disk, update it and write again.

```
createDataset(name, data) {
    const state = loadState();
    state.datasets = [
      ...state.datasets,
      {name, size: data.length}
    ];
    storeState(state);

    const file = loadDataset();
    file.datasets = [
      ...file.datasets,
      {name, data}
    ];
    storeDataset(file);
  }
```

Where methods `loadState(), storeState(), loadDataset(), storeDataset()` uses initial methods.

```
const loadState = () => 
  load(stateFilePath);
const storeState = state => 
  store(stateFilePath, state);
...
const loadDataset = () =>
  load(datasetFilePath);
const storeDataset = dataset => 
  store(datasetFilePath, dataset);
```

I'm using a package from `npm` called `readline-sync` to create a simple "terminal", I don't know if it causes some conflicts.

The source code is in the Github: [Git repo](https://github.com/leandroungari/database-comparative/tree/feature/list-dataset/src/app). In the file "index.js", the method `createDataset()` calls `loadState()` and `storeState()`, which both uses the methods showed above.

The package `readline-sync` is used in the interpreter, here [Interpreter file](https://github.com/leandroungari/database-comparative/blob/feature/list-dataset/src/interpreter/index.js), which basic loops until exit command.

Just as note, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 and Node.js 10.15.0. To make this code I saw an example, in the [YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/TZRMh4BZTS0?t=430). This guy is using a MAC OS X, I really hope that the system won't be problem.

Comment: Maybe because that function is launched only when the program ends ?

Comment: Where is the rest of your [mcve]?

Comment: Ok, just a minute.

Comment: @leandroungari: that code is still not yet complete or verifiable (could be more minimal too)

Comment: @leandroungari: "I add Git repo link" - yes, my comment refers to that. Note the "still".

Comment: @TGrif No, it loops waiting next command.